# How to listen the 400 (Bad Request) with Angular *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I won't paste any code, since this is a general question. I need to figure out how to listen if nothing returns. I can't get any objects, since nothing exists. I only receive on my `GET` request a message "`400 (Bad Request)`".(console).

How can I disable a button if there is a "`400 (Bad Request)`" (nothing exists)?

Is there a way to listen this on frontend?

Thanks

Comment: As you provide no code it's hard to help.
http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(res => {...}, err => { console.log(err.status) });
// would write 400 in the console.

Comment: Starting from here you can do everything you want with it.

Comment: give me a sec please :)

Comment: I get 'undefined'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 you would need to capture the error from the response.

```
badRequest: boolean = false;

this.appService.myHttpCall.subscribe(
   data =>  // do something with success,
   error => {
       if(error.status == 400){
          this.badRequest = true;
       }
   });
```

And use the result in your template.  If you really want to go the `*ngIf` route you would do this:

```
<button *ngIf="badRequest" type="button" disabled>My Button</button>
<button *ngIf="!badRequest" type="button">My Button</button>
```

You would essentially have to code two buttons, both with `*ngIf` statements to get the result you want.

If you want to use the `[disabled]` attribute you would do this:

```
<button [disabled]="badRequest" type="button">My Button</button>
```

However, I would not disabled a button if a BadRequest happens, because then how would the user resubmit the form after correctly filling it out?  For example, if the user leaves a required field blank, the server returns a BadRequest and disables the button.  Then the user cannot correct the missing field and re-submit the form.

What I would do instead is to toggle the button's `disabled` attribute based on the validity of the form like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">

   ...inputs....    

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a form, so [disabled] works perfectlly.

Comment: Great.  Glad it worked for you.  Sorry, I just made the assumption it was a form.

Comment: It's still not working on page load, only when I click the button it dissapears. How can I make it to listen the page load? Pure Javascript, or?

Comment: If you are using a local variable, such as `badRequest: boolean = false;` are you giving it a default value or just using `badRequest: boolean;`?

Comment: I'm giving it a value 'false'.

Comment: I can't duplicate that problem.  If I use `badRequest = false;` in my component and `<button [disabled]="badRequest" type="button">My Button</button>` in my template, the button is visible until there is a bad request.  If I want it to not be visible at startup, I use `badRequest = true;`

Comment: Exactly. I need to find a way to 'listen' to it somehow, so the button would be either visible or hidden on page load, depending of the true/false logic. Care to join in a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137349/discussion-between-tyler-jennings-and-eric-dummy).

Comment: I'm there. :) Waiting for you.